# What is the time complexity of DataRow indexer?

Tags: c#, ado.net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

What is the time complexity of accessing a column by its name in an instance of DataRow?

```
object Foo(DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    // What is the time complexity of the below line O(1) / O(n) / ?
    return row[columnName];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a peek with [Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) and can confirm that the code in question has a time complexity of O(1).  The actual data is stored in DataColumn instances using a plain old array indexed by record number...one array per column.  The DataColumn is obtained from the name via a Hashtable and the record number is obtained directly from the DataRow instance.  So you have a hash table lookup and an array lookup both of which are O(1).

Comment: Chapeau for your efforts and investigation! You made me to look in Reflector by myself and understand how it really works. 
Thanks a lot!